# Is mummy coming home yet?

Tags: questions

> Is mummy coming home yet?
>
> Is mummy home?

What are the different between them?

Is it the first mean whether his or her mother is coming home and the second is he wants to know is mummy at home?

Comment: Correct. And I would capitalize "Mummy" since we're using it as a name and spell "coming" with one "m" if this sentence is set in modern times (or is it always with two m's in British English as the use of "Mummy" would indicate?).

Comment: The first one doesn't sound fine to me. I would recommend you use present perfect. "Has mummy come home?"

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang "Coming" is spelled with one "m" in BrE too.

Comment: And seeing user178049's comment, I would say that user178049's suggestion and the questions you have proposed are all correct, depending on the situation.

Comment: @user178049 Saying "Has Mummy come home?" has a different meaning to the first sentence, it is asking whether Mummy has already **arrived** at home, where the first sentence is asking whether Mummy is **currently travelling** home.

Comment: As a side comment, in the UK, saying "mummy" will make you sound like a child or like you are posh. Most people would use the shortened "Mum" (or some similar regional variation, e.g. "Mam") to refer to their mother.

Comment: @SteveES I suspect whether Mummy has already arrived at home is what the OP meant to say. And if they are asking whether Mummy is currently "traveling" home, I wouldn't use yet.

Comment: @user178049 I just wanted to make it clear to the OP that there was a difference in meaning. I think the use of "yet" is fine, if, for example, you are waiting for her at home, especially if she is late. That said, I would probably be more likely to ask "Has she left yet?" in that sort of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is mummy coming home yet?" means "has mummy started to travel home at this time?"

"Is mummy home" means "is mummy currently in her house?"